# Error Message "You don't have permission to access /register.php on this server"?

Tags: php, registration

I am getting the following error when trying to use my `register.php` script.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /register.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Here is the script :

```
<?php //error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', true);
include('header.php');
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $sec[$key] = filter($value);
}

$verificare1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='{$sec['user']}' OR `email`='{$sec['email']}'");
$verificare = mysql_num_rows($verificare1);

if ($verificare > 0) {
$mesaj = "<div class=\"error\">ERROR: Username or email already registered!</div>";
}else if (!isUserID($sec['user'])) {
$mesaj = "<div class=\"error\">ERROR: Username is incorrect!</div>";
}else if(!isEmail($sec['email'])) {
$mesaj = "<div class=\"error\">ERROR: Enter a valid email address!</div>";
}else if (!checkPwd($sec['password'],$sec['password2'])) {
$mesaj = "<div class=\"error\">ERROR: Passwords do not match!</div>";
}else{
if(isset($_COOKIE['PlusREF'])){
$ref = $_COOKIE['PlusREF'];
$user1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$ref}'");
$user = mysql_fetch_object($user1);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `referals`(user,referal,date) values('{$user->login}','{$sec['user']}',NOW())");
}
$activare = rand(000000000, 999999909);
mail($sec['email'],"Welcome to ExchangeBoost.com","
Hello,

Thank you for signing up at ExchangeBoost.com. 

Click on the link below in order to activate your account: 
{$site->site_url}/activate.php?cod={$activare}

If you would like after you activate your account you can buy coins in the UserCP at a very low rate.

Thank you!","From: ExchangeBoost.com <{$site->site_email}>");
$final = VisitorIP();
$passa = $sec['password'];
$passc = MD5($passa);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(email,login,coins,IP,pass,passdecoded,ref,signup,activate) values('{$sec['email']}','{$sec['user']}','100','$final','$passc','$passa','{$ref}',NOW(),'{$activare}')")or die(mysql_error());
$mesaj = "<div class=\"success\">Registered! You need to confirm your email address now!</div>";
}}
?>  
<div class="main">


            <div class="content-ex">


<div class="msg"><?echo $mesaj;?></div>
<form action="" method="post">

                         <p>
                             <label>Username</label><br/>
                             <input class="text big" type="text" value="" name="user"/>
                         </p>
                         <p>
                             <label>Email</label><br/>
                             <input class="text big" type="email" value="" name="email"/>
                         </p>
                         <p>
                             <label>Password</label> <br/>
                             <input class="text big" type="password" value="" name="password"/>
                         </p>
                         <p>
                             <label>Repeat Password</label> <br/>
                             <input class="text big" type="password" value="" name="password2"/>
                         </p>
                          <p>

                            <input type="submit" class="bbut" value="Register" name="register" />
                          </p>

                    </form>

            </div>
<div class="signin"> 
               <h2>Sign In</h2>
                           <form method="post">

<input class="text big" type="text" value="Username:" name="login">
<input class="text big" type="password" value="Password:" name="pass">           

<div class="buttons">

                            <input type="submit" class="gbut" name="logare" value="Login" /><a class="bbut" href="register.php" name="logare" value="Register">Register</a>
<br><br>
<a href="recover.php">Dude, I forgot my password!</a>
</div>                                        
</form>

            </div>



        </div>


<?include('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: paste code from register.php and some directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that File is really exists or not.It exists then check your `.htaccess` settings. `404 Error` means the page you are looking for is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a file permissions error. Are you on a windows or *nix hosting environment? What are the permissions on the file set too? Ensure the web user has permission to read to the file.

Answer (score 0):

these are two errors

1. as the error message states, you don't have permission to access the file at the path.
   -> you in this case means the webserver process that is handling the request, for example apache. You need to check the file permissions, make sure that the file can be read by the web server. Further, you need to check if the path is correct, it looks for register.php directly in the web root directory
2. your webserver is configured to deliver an error (html) document, but this error document (for example 404.html) could not be found